# Installing a full MySQL install silently using NSIS

Tags: mysql, installation, windows-installer, silent-installer

I have a basic NSIS script setup like so:

```
!include MUI2.nsh
!include WordFunc.nsh
!insertmacro VersionCompare
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include InstallOptions.nsh
!include nsDialogs.nsh

Name "sqltest"
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE_RIGHT

OutFile "sqltest.exe"
InstallDir "$PROGRAMFILES\sqltest"
RequestExecutionLevel admin

XPStyle on

!define MUI_WELCOMEPAGE_TEXT "The MySQL Test Install"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
;!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM
;!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

Section "install"
    
    SetOutPath $INSTDIR
    File /r "V:\Installers\MySQL\Release\*.*"
    ExecWait '"$SYSDIR\msiExec" /i "$INSTDIR\mysql.msi" /passive'
    
    
SectionEnd
```

However, this only seems to install another installer:

[image: mysql install folder]

If I run the .msi file manually I get to choose "full" and the process actually installs MySQL in full, with the service running etc.

How can I achieve this kind of install, silently, using NSIS?

**Update:**

I tried a lot of various commands and found that nothing I did installed the full MySQL with arguments. I managed to install MySQL full, but this didn't install the service and other key features (top part of http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql-installer/en/mysql-installer-news-1-4-12.html)

I tried the second section of the above link, with no luck. All it did was install a folder with the options shown in the image above.

I tried using the command installer, as the poster below alluded to. However, this gave me an Oracle login prompt! I need to install and this this up without user interaction.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: This has nothing to do with NSIS, please remove the NSIS tag.

Comment: It seems there are more than one .msi for MySQL, which did you download? Community edition?

Comment: Yes, community edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be possible to continue the installation by executing MySQLInstallerConsole as documented [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/MySQLInstallerConsole.html) but it is of course much better to get the .msi to perform the installation and to do that you need to figure out the right parameters to pass to msiexec.

These parameters are only known to the authors of the .msi and I had a really hard time finding documentation for it on the MySQL website. The only place I found any useful information was in the installer release notes!

I found some references to `installdir` and `datadir` parameters [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql-installer/en/mysql-installer-news-1-4-10.html). I'm not sure if these are MSI parameters or if they go in the `CONSOLEARGS` string.

When using the `/passive` switch it seems you are able to pass a string parameter called `CONSOLEARGS` and it supports a lot of options as documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql-installer/en/mysql-installer-news-1-4-12.html):

```
msiexec /i mysql-installer-community-5.6.27.1.msi /passive CONSOLEARGS="install -type=Full -silent"
```

or

```
msiexec /i mysql-installer-community-5.6.27.1.msi /passive CONSOLEARGS="install server;5.6.27;x64:*:type=config;openfirewall=true;generallog=true;binlog=true;serverid=1;enable_tcpip=true;port=3306;rootpasswd=secret:type=user;username=root;password=secret;role=DBManager -silent"
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer @Anders, I'll check out the arguments and do some more trial and error to see how far I get!

Comment: I've been trying a lot of stuff. My feedback is in my OP. Any ideas?

Comment: I have never installer MySQL so I don't know. You could try asking on their forum. This topic seems to be related to your problem: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?169,647447,647447#msg-647447

Comment: I have managed to get it to install. There are issues with the arguments but your answer helped me at least get it to install

Comment: The second command does not work. It does not allow to select specific components. And it is not silent either

Answer (score 0):

In the installer script will copy the file "mysql.msi" to the installation directory. First, create the mysql.msi file in the same directory as the installer script below then compile the installer script. If the installer script is on the Desktop, delete the mysql.msi file before running the compiled installer. Running the simple installer installs the mysql.msi file to the Desktop.

You will have to modify the script as follows:

```
ExecWait '"$SYSDIR\msiExec" /i "$INSTDIR\mysql.msi" /qn'
```

Comment: Answers should be solutions, not suggestions. Does this solve the problem? Then please explain how and don't simply say "try". Is it merely a suggestion and you're not sure if it does solve the problem? Then this is not an answer. Please clarify to avoid this getting flagged and deleted, thanks!